# LT Spice Comparator Question

Tags: ltspice, digital-comparator

Does LT Spice have any way of creating a 4-bit Comparator with outputs A=B, A>B, A

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? LTSpice does have digital gate devices, but they're a bit of a pain to use. SPICE is not designed for digital simulations.

Comment: Basically creating an elevator and I want to compare the elevator's current floor with the destination floor. My professor suggested LT Spice because of the waveform feature and its accuracy detecting glitches, but if this sounds like it'd be too much I can switch to Logisim for the purposes of this assignment. As an aside, what would you say SPICE is primarily designed for? I got the impression it was meant for this kind of circuit design. I have used it a few other times for various digital simulations, but those were less complicated than this elevator, admittedly.

Comment: It's for transistor level circuit design. That could mean designing a logic gate. But when it comes time to combine 10's or 1000's of gates to make a digital design, SPICE is overkill. If you want to design your comparator up from transistors, then SPICE is a good tool. You'd do it by combining transistors in the ways you've learned for designing gates.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information! Is there any particular circuit design/simulation software you would suggest? If I had more time I might try to build something with transistors but that would be pretty overkill for the purposes of this assignment.

Comment: You can do this with an HDL simulator like Modelsim or Aldec (or the free ones that come with FPGA design tools). Getting glitch behavior right will require adjusting the delays of the individual gates correctly.

Comment: @ThePhoton Why wwould you say they're "a bit of pain"? Compared to what? They're very malleable and their behaviour in switching waveforms is exquisite. Nothing comes close to it. Are you referring to the need to fill in the parameters? If so, I find that a very minor price to pay for having such control not only over the output, but a glitch-free simulation, too, since they're sure to have no discontinuities.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen a spice simulation is going to have a hard time simulating 1000's of component's and take up much more computing resources than an HDL simulator. Use the tool that best fits the job.

Comment: @laptop2d True, but that's why I asked "compared to what?". The rest of my comment was related to LTspice and its use, according to the OP. I do agree LTspice, or SPICE, in general, are analog simulators and they will not excel in the digital world, but the OP wasn't about HDL or others.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, TBH, I haven't used them often, but I remember having to figure out some tricks, like which of the 8 pins are used for a given gate, what is the funny extra pin for, maybe some other details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that should be fairly easy:

Step 1) Create a B-source

Step 2) Set the B-source value to an expression like this:

```
V=IF(V(node)>1,1,2)
```

where the first term is the expression A>B or whatever, the second term is the voltage if true, and the third term is the voltage if false. (I think I have my logic right)

You can do a lot of other algebraic expressions with B-sources, including laplace transfer functions.  Use A==B and keep in mind that if you do this V(node)==1 you'll never see this happen in a normal simulation so you'll need to if statements (A>1.1)&(B<1.0) so you capture a range of voltages or a rounding function.

OR

There are some digital devices:

From [LT spice wiki](http://ltwiki.org/index.php5?title=Undocumented_LTspice):

> Documented directly in Help:
>       Buf (aka Buf1 Inv)
>       AND
>       OR
>       XOR – when more than two inputs are present, uses the correct definition of true if one and only one input is true, rather than the more common incorrect definition of true if an odd number of inputs > are true (which should be called an ODD/NODD gate rather than an XOR/XNOR gate).
>       Schmitt (aka SchmittBuf SchmittInv DifSchmitt DiffSchmittBuf iffSchmittInv)
>       Dflop (CLR takes precedence over PRE, also a start up state may be set – see SRflop)
>       Varistor
>       Modulator (aka Modulate Modulate2)

which I've never used, but they are there.

Comment: Thank you! I just switched to Logisim for this simulation but I will definitely remember that for the future.

Comment: If you like the answer upvote and mark

Comment: Why would you propose behavioural sources over A-devices? If multiple logic is needed, use `.mach`. Anything is better than a behavioural source. Just because it allows you to do it quickly, it doesn't mean it behaves better.

Comment: I never proposed b sources over A-devices, I presented them both and specifically put in a capital OR to show that. What is the problem?

Comment: @laptop2d Your last words "which I've never used, but they are there" suggest a minization or some sort, as in they are of a lesser importance, which I find not true. Any logical operation with a behavioural source will introduce discontinuities, which may cause "hiccups" (unless taken care of with extra components). A-devices have builtin smooth edges that specifically avoid them. Beh. src. also need to calculate every point dynamically, at every step of the way, and they will sacrifice precision for it, anytime, their dynamic range is poor. They are versatile, though, but that's about it.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen if thats the way you read it I never intended for it to read that way, I'm sorry you had a misunderstanding